# Dissolve object starting from the bottom

Tags: unity, shaders, unity-shader-graph

I'm currently getting into using the new "Unity Shader Graph"s and have made an OK dissolve shader that looks like this:

[image: dissolve_shader]

My next goal is to move this effect so the object dissolves bottom-up. This is where I'm stuck. I tried blending this effect with another effect that just fades the object from the bottom up but this does not create the effect I am looking for (#1 is the fade effect, #2 is the two shaders blended together):

[image: down_up_fade]
[image: wrong_fade]

The end effect should look something like this:

[image: wanted_effect]

**How can I achieve this effect?** Answers do not have to be specific to Unity and a good answer should include the thought-process to creating this effect, not just code or pictures of a shader graph.

Answer (score 3):

This [Ominous Games dev blog post](https://ominousgames.com/2017/12/29/the-great-disappearing-act-making-of-a-possession-effect/) has a rather detailed explanation & code samples that acheives a similar looking effect.

**Summary of steps:**

- Use a grayscale noise texture to fade mesh alpha based on an interpolation factor.
- Use model-space fragment position to control dissolution based on a specified direction vector.
- Combine texture- and geometry-based alpha/clipping control to create a hybrid dissolve effect.
- Add in a glow effect by "predicting" the next areas to dissolve and adjusting model emission accordingly.